# Fiware Orion context broker subscriptions condition does not work

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am using Orion Context Broker version 1.1.0

I had the only entity in my DB:

```
{
  "id"=>"Room1",
  "type"=>"Room",
  "temperature"=>{"type"=>"none", "value"=>10, "metadata"=>{}}
}
```

I did not have any `subscription`.

Then I created 3 `subscriptions`:

```
[
{
  "subject"=>{"entities"=>[{"id"=>"Room1", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>""}],
  "condition"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], "expression"=>{"q"=>"temperature>10"}}}
},
 {
  "subject"=>{"entities"=>[{"id"=>"Room1", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>""}],
  "condition"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], "expression"=>{"q"=>"temperature<10"}}}
},
 {
  "subject"=>{"entities"=>[{"id"=>"Room1", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>""}],
  "condition"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], "expression"=>{"q"=>"temperature==10"}}}
}
]
```

As you can see, the difference is only in the expressions:  ***temperature>10***, ***temperature<10***, ***temperature==10***.

So that any time I change the **Room1** *temperature* I should have only one `subscription` triggering the notification.

**But it does not work as it should !!!**

Each time I change the *temperature*, I have all 3 notifications.

However, when `subscriptions` were created, only one of them triggered a notification, depending on the `temperature` value of the Room1. It worked as expected.

But when `Room1 temperature` is changed, it does not work correctly and triggers all 3 notifications.

**Edit:**
Full output of the GET /v2/subscriptions operation:

```
[
  {
    "id"=>"574716a22fe8cdc00a696a94",
    "expires"=>"2017-04-05T14:00:00.00Z",
    "status"=>"active",
    "subject"=>{
      "entities"=>[{"id"=>"Room1", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>""}],    
      "condition"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], 
      "expression"=>{"q"=>"temperature>10"}}
    }, 
    "notification"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], "http"=>{"url"=>"http://localhost:1028/accumulate"}},
    "throttling"=>5
  },
  {
    "id"=>"574716a22fe8cdc00a696a95",
    "expires"=>"2017-04-05T14:00:00.00Z",
    "status"=>"active",
    "subject"=>{
      "entities"=>[{"id"=>"Room1", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>""}],  
      "condition"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], 
      "expression"=>{"q"=>"temperature<10"}}
    },
    "notification"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], "http"=>{"url"=>"http://localhost:1028/accumulate"}},
    "throttling"=>5},
  {
    "id"=>"574716a22fe8cdc00a696a96",
    "expires"=>"2017-04-05T14:00:00.00Z",
    "status"=>"active",
    "subject"=>{
      "entities"=>[{"id"=>"Room1", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>""}], 
      "condition"=>{"attrs"=>["temperature"], 
      "expression"=>{"q"=>"temperature==10"}}
    },
    "notification"=>{"timesSent"=>2, "lastNotification"=>"2016-05-26T15:30:42.00Z", "attrs"=>["temperature"], "http"=>{"url"=>"http://localhost:1028/accumulate"}},
    "throttling"=>5
  }
]
```

**Edit2:** Add some scenario:

1. Changed `Room1 temperature` to 11
2. Had the same output, but 
   `[...{"timesSent"=>1}..., ...{"timesSent"=>1}..., ...{"timesSent"=>3}...]`
3. Changed `Room1 temperature` to 10
4. Had the same output, but 
   `[...{"timesSent"=>2}..., ...{"timesSent"=>2}..., ...{"timesSent"=>4}...]`
5. Changed `Room1 temperature` to 9
6. Had the same output, but 
   `[...{"timesSent"=>3}..., ...{"timesSent"=>3}..., ...{"timesSent"=>5}...]`

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the output of the `GET /v2/subscriptions` operation, please? Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer, added the output of the GET /v2/subscriptions operation,

Comment: Looking to the result, note that only the last subscription (`574716a22fe8cdc00a696a96`) should `timesSent` and `lastNotification`, i.e. it seems that only the last one has been triggered...

Comment: Let's have a look to notification payload you are getting... could you edit your question to include the notification payloads you get (triggered by the corresponding updates), please? Thanks!

Comment: I added a scenario and output results. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Having also the notifications payload you get at `http://localhost:1028/accumulate` a each "Changed Room1 temperature ..." step would be useful (maybe the question post is not the place for that, but you could use for example http://pastebin.com and include the link in the question post).

Comment: After changing to 10 again: http://pastebin.com/arNbdUtp
After changing to 15: http://pastebin.com/a6Nwfa0r

Comment: Looking to your pastebin logs, in each case the Fiware-Correlator header is equal in the 3 notifications. That confirms that 3 have the same origin, i.e. the same update context. And, at the same time, each notification shows a different subcriptionId, which confirms that each one is triggered by a different subscriptions. In addition, the subscriptionId matches with the ones you have in your `GET /v2/subscritipons` output. This is weird... I'll try to reproduce the same case in my environment, in order to see how it goes. Keep tuned :)

Comment: It could be related with subscription cache. Could you re-try running CB with `-noCache` CLI option, please?

Comment: This helped ! It started working after I ran the contextBroker with `-noCache` CLI option. Is this alright to have this option enabled ?

Comment: Yes, it is allright from a functional perspective. From a performance perspective, you could lose some performance but it wouldn't be noticeable except if you are working in a high load environment (i.e. thousands of update context requests per second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a problem in subscriptions cache management in Orion 1.1. So, the solution in that version is to disable cache using `-noCache` [CLI option](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/admin/cli/index.html).

The bug has been identified and [a github issue has been created about it](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2202). It will be fixed in a newer Orion version.

**EDIT:** the bug has been solved in development branch, so it would be ready in Orion 1.2, to be release by early June 2016.

Comment: Edit about bugfixing for Orion 1.2